# Unexpected outcome of assigning one char pointer to another (different addresses)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I would expect these two pointer to share the same exact address if I do this:

```
char* foo, * bar=new char;
// or even
// char* foo=new char, * bar=new char;

bar = "Bar string";
foo = bar;

cout << "Foo: " << foo << " (" << &foo << ")" << endl;
cout << "Bar: " << bar << " (" << &bar << ")" << endl;

Output:
Foo: Bar string (0049F890)
Bar: Bar string (0049F884)
```

Yet, I get a slightly different (but different) addresses of them both. Is there anything like "explicit" assignment for cases like this? Not that I really need it, I'm investigating why they end up having different addresses when I assigned the **address** of one to be equal to the other's **address**?

Answer (score 2):

`&foo` and `&bar` are the addresses of the **variables**. Because there are two variables, they have different addresses.

The values held by the two variables are the same though. Confirm that by testing that

```
foo == bar
```

For what it is worth, the use of `new` is pointless since you immediately throw away the values that are returned, and hence leak the memory. It should be

```
char *bar = "Bar string";
char *foo = bar;
cout << foo == bar << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the (char*) address foo and bar point to.

This is due to the overloads definitions of the `<<` operator:

- Passing a `char*` (first case) prints the string it points to. For any other pointer type, it would print the pointer address. But for `char*`, the behavior is special : it prints the value pointed to.
- Passing a `char**` (second case) prints its raw value, ia a pointer to a pointer to `char`. This is the default behavior of the operator for passing a pointer other than `char*`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

This means you are printing:

- The string foo and bar point to (first case)
- The adress of the variable containing foo and bar. These are stack variables, and since foo and bar are different variables, their addresses are different

You could cast foo and bar to `void*` in order to print their value as raw pointers:

```
cout << "Foo: " << foo << " (" << (void*)foo << ")" << endl;
cout << "Bar: " << bar << " (" << (void*)bar << ")" << endl;
```

**Side note** : you are allocating a char on the heap in the first line, and set the pointers to another value afterwards, without deleting them. Thus you are leaking memory.

Comment: Re: your side note - Does that mean my `bar = "Bar string"` is not being stored on the heap (where I allocated memory for it) but rather somewhere else? Because that is what I thought it would happen.

Comment: @developer10: Your `new` does not allocate memory for `bar`. `bar` is a local pointer variable with automatic storage duration. It initially *points to* memory allocated by `new`; once you reassign it to point to the string literal `"Bar string"`, it no longer has any relationship whatsoever with the dynamically allocated memory. Generally, you seem to have a lot of misconceptions about C++ memory management. It is unclear why you don't just use `std::string`.

Comment: @developer10 : no, bar = "Bar string" does not copy the string to the memory allocated. It changes the pointer value to the adress of the literal string "Bar string" which is already allocated somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are printing addresses at which your `bar` and `foo` vairables are stored. Both of these variables are pointers, so the behaviour is the same.

What you probably looking for is cast both variables to `(void*)` using `reinterpret_cast()`: `reinterpret_cast<void*>(foo)` and `reinterpret_cast<void*> (bar)`, which will print the **starting memory location of where both variables point to**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* foo, *bar = new char;

    bar = "Bar string";
    foo = bar;

    cout << "Foo: " << foo << " (" << &foo << "," << reinterpret_cast<void*>(foo) << ")" << endl;
    cout << "Bar: " << bar << " (" << &bar << "," << reinterpret_cast<void*>(bar) << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same as the other answer: Why C-style casts? `reinterpret_cast<void*>` would be clearer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl totally agree, changed my answer.